# Bars' order in combined plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, grouped-bar-chart

I need to change the order of combined bars on a plot - first 'group_b', last 'group_a'. It seems like very simple ... but I have no good idea.

I can change columns name, after that to change a legend and get what I need - but I think it is a wrong way.

I have checked similar questions and didn't find an answer(((

Is there any simple and clear way to do it?

[image]

Comment: call the `plt.plot(group_b, ...)` first, before the analogous `group_a` plot. The order should change then.

Comment: It doesn't work:
```ax = plt1.plot(x=['group_b','group_a'], kind='bar')
ax.set_title('Index per dates')
ax.set_ylabel('Index')
ax.set_xlabel('Date');
'''
ValueError: x must be a label or position

Comment: that's a different question and error altogether now. Just executing your old code with the exception of swapping two functions around should not cause something like that.

Comment: @Dion, your solution won't work here, because they are not calling matplotlib's `plt.plot` function, instead they have a pandas DataFrame called `plt1`, on which they are calling the `.plot()` method, which is plotting both sets of bars in one command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas` will plot the bars according to the order of the columns in the dataframe. So we just need to reorder the columns to get the plot you want.

Consider the following:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'group_a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'group_b': [6, 5, 4, 3, 2]})

df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()

my_order = ['group_b', 'group_a']
df[my_order].plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

The first image, before we reordered, has `group_a` first:
[image]

The second image, after reordering, has `group_b` first:
[image]